# What is the difference between structured and unstructured programming?

Tags: structured-programming

I think structured programming is such a programming which can be divided into some module to make a program easy. (If I am wrong then kindly inform me make the correction of the concept) But C program is one kind of structured programming. So what  unstructured programming is? Can't we divide it into some module?? And if it is then can we tell it the older version of programming languages and the structured programming is the newer version? And is it the main difference between them?

Comment: are you you talking about Spaghetti code? [Here is a quick link](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-structured-and-unstructured-programming-language)

Answer (score 0):

Unstructured program is execute sequential order, complex readability, difficult to compiling. This program not jumped any line of code.
On the other hand,
Structured program is convert large or complex program into manageable, small code of pieces which are called functions/ modules/ subprograms of large complex program.